# Repro steps problem during selecting Wok items by ID in TFS2018.Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS2018.Visual Studio 2017. If I look for a word ex. george in TFS web, cannot select WITs by ID, it shows:

`TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by Repro Steps.`

We used to use TFS2013, three months ago we updated for a version TFS2018 a now we found this problem. 
We never used field repro steps. The field is not configured in xml for bug,task or change request. Is it hardcoded in TFS search editor ?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2013 the "Repro Steps" has name "Steps to Reproduce". Upgrade process does not rename it. However TFS 2018 tries to use "Repro Steps". You can check that with [witadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work?view=azure-devops-2019) command line and [field sub-commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/manage-work-item-fields?view=azure-devops-2019).

1. Check the field name:

witadmin listfields /collection:CollectionURL /n:Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps

2. Rename the field:

witadmin changefield /collection:CollectionURL /n:Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps /name:"Repro Steps"

Answer (score 0):

The error fairly clearly states that the issue is with the "Repro Steps" field. We would suggest you first check if the field exist in the source system by exactly this name.

That field is only present some [work item types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983994.aspx). depending on your process template selection.

Work items can contain any number of fields, as defined by the process template. You can access the actual fields by inspecting the [`Fields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.fields(v=vs.120).aspx) property on the work item object.

You can run [witadmin listfields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236909.aspx) to find all the fields that your collection uses.

If you still get error after having that field. Please also try to [delete your TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).